# Remove duplicates in a php array and display 10 results at a time

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop, duplicates

I'm trying to create a php array and remove the dupes - which I've successfully done.  Now I need to display 10 results at a time - as there will be 10 unique results from the array per page on this web app I'm building.

The duplicate removal seems to be working, but not my While loop, as it doesn't give me 10 results.

```
    <?php
    echo "DUPES: <br>";
    $dupes = array("one", "two", "two", "two", "two", "three", "four", "five", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve");
    echo "<pre>";
    echo print_r($dupes);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<br><br>";

    echo "REMOVED DUPES: <br>";
    $removed_dupes = array_unique($dupes);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo print_r(array_unique($removed_dupes));
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<br><br>";

    echo "WHILE LOOP TO SHOW ONLY NON DUPES: <br><br>";

    $x = 0;

    while ($x < 11) {
        if ($removed_dupes[$x] != "") {
            echo " The number is: $removed_dupes[$x]" . "<br>";
            $x++;
        } else {
            $x++;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What do you get at the end?

Comment: Just want to point this out: `if (...) { $x++; } else { $x++; }`

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$removed_dupes = array_values(array_unique($dupes));
```

[array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) will keep your old indexes as it is,
[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will reset your indexes.

It should work.

Comment: A shame there isn't a flag to do that with `array_unique`.

Comment: Nice!  This worked!!  I just had to change it slightly to:

$removed_dupes = array_values(array_unique($dupes));

Comment: Ohh, Yes, I corrected my answer. Thanks ! Welcome Too :)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : At first sight, I thought of that only but then I end up with array_values

Comment: If your problem has been solved by my solution, you can accept my answer !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of this:

```
 $x = 0;

    while ($x < 11) {
        if ($removed_dupes[$x] != "") {
            echo " The number is: $removed_dupes[$x]" . "<br>";
            $x++;
        } else {
            $x++;
        }
    }
```

you can have:

```
for ($i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (empty($removed_dupes[$i])) {
        echo " The number is: $removed_dupes[$x]" . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Shorter, cleaner and clearer I suppose.

Comment: But... now every iteration of the loop will increase `i` by `2`, won't it? Also, `$i` vs `$x`.

Comment: How about `for ($i=0;i<10;$i++){echo empty($removed_dupes[$i]) ? "" : "Unique number :" . $removed_dupes[$i] . "<br>";}`?

Answer (score 0):

> After the use of array_unique() function, You need to re-initialise the index of array and it can be done by using array_values() function.

```
$removed_dupes = array_values($removed_dupes)

while ($x < 11) {
        if ($removed_dupes[$x] != "") {
            echo " The number is: $removed_dupes[$x]" . "<br>";
            $x++;
        } else {
            $x++;
        }
    }
```